# Datatables bases de datos relacionadas

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables, datatable

Resulta que estoy bastante atascado con un problema.
Necesito crear una **tabla con datatable** que muestre los datos de una base de datos. Hasta aquí sin problemas, el tema es que **esta base de datos está relacionada con otra** y evidentemente, sólo me muestra el ID.
Me gustaría que renderizara el nombre que se relaciona con este ID en la otra tabla.
He probado a hacerlo con una función que llama por ajax a estos datos, pero al ser una tarea asíncrona no consigo que renderice el nombre (por consola sí lo saca).

¿Alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
jQuery('#tabla-invitaciones').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: false,
            ajax: {
                url: "/wp-content/plugins/mis-invitaciones/get-post/getTable.php",
                data: {
                    table: 'ws_invitaciones'
                },
                dataSrc: "",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
            },
            columns: [{
                    data: "id"
                },
                {
                    data: "nombre",
                    render: function(data, type, full) {
                        return '<input value="' + data + '" name="nombre" data-edit="true">';
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: "etiqueta_id",
                    render: function(data, type, full) {
                        var result = jQuery.ajax({
                            type: "get",
                            url: "/wp-content/plugins/mis-invitaciones/get-post/get-tag.php",
                            data: {
                                id: data,
                            },
                            success: function(json) {
                                var nombre = JSON.parse(json)[0].nombre
                                console.log(nombre) //devuelve lo que toca
                                return nombre;
                            },
                            error: function(xhr, status) {
                                //alert('Ha habido un problema al eliminar el ID:<' + id + '> en la tabla <' + table + '>.');
                            }

                        });
                        return result;
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: "mensaje",
                    render: function(data, type, full) {
                        return '<textarea name="mensaje" data-edit="true">' + data + '</textarea>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: "solo_digital",
                    render: function(data, type, full) {
                        if (data == 1) {
                            return '<input type="checkbox" name="solo_digital" data-edit="true" checked>'
                        } else {
                            return '<input type="checkbox" name="solo_digital" data-edit="true">'
                        }
                    }

                },
                {
                    data: "id",
                    render: function(data, type, full) {
                        var url = "https://rosayjavier.galileaestudio.es?inv=" + data;
                        return '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + url + '</a>';
                    }

                },
                {
                    data: "id",
                    render: function(data, type, full) {

                        return '' +
                            '<a onclick="ws_saveRow(' + data + ',this)"><i class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk"></i></a>' +
                            '<a onclick="ws_deleteRow(' + data + ',\'ws_invitaciones\',\'#tabla-invitaciones\')"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i></a>'

                    }

                }
            ],
            language: es_ES
        })
```

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: puedes mostrar lo que te saca ws_invitaciones en un console.log???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es complejo tienes que hacer una consulta limpia con las relaciones resueltas.
te aconsejo hacer una vista para que la información sea fácilmente mostrada.

así lo único que debes modificar es la vista para que te muestre las relaciones que deseas.

NOTA: pones código pero eso no es lo que falla, sino el php que responde a la consulta ajax.

ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
precio INT NOT NULL,
producto VARCHAR(30),
proveedor INT NOT NULL,
date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
INSERT INTO tabla (precio,producto,proveedor) values 
(500,'producto 1',1),
(200,'producto 1',2),
(300,'producto 1',3),
(400,'producto 1',4);
CREATE TABLE provedor (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
nombre VARCHAR(30),
otro_dato VARCHAR(30),
date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
INSERT INTO provedor (id,nombre,otro_dato) values 
(1,'prooveedor 1','A1'),
(2,'prooveedor 2','B2'),
(3,'prooveedor 3','C3'),
(4,'prooveedor 4','D4');

CREATE VIEW datatable1 AS 
select tabla.id,tabla.precio,tabla.producto,provedor.nombre from tabla
left join provedor on (tabla.proveedor=provedor.id);

select * from datatable1;
```

[Aquí el ejemplo funcional](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mVyoDVdqNAn3fksw8CoEx2/4)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! No sabía que se podían hacer vistas SQL. Con esto está perfecto.

Comment: Todos los días se aprende algo nuevo